# Nav menu classes 'has-dropdown' but no 'active'

Tags: menus, dropdown

I have a nav menu with a depth of 2.

```
wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary_navigation',
                    'depth'          => 2
) );
```

When I am active on a page in the nav menu that has no children, that `li` menu item has `active` appended. However, when the menu item has children, `has-children` is appended, but no 'active' or even a related class name.

```
<ul id="menu-main-top-navigation">
    <li class="parent1"></li>
    <li class="has-dropdown not-click">
        <ul class="dropdown">
            <li class="child1"></li>
            <li class="child2"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="parent3"></li>
    <li class="parent4"></li>
    <li class="active parent5"></li>
    <li class="parent6"></li>
</ul>
```

In this case I am the page relating to menu item 'parent5'. This is fine. When I navigate to what is meant to be 'parent2', the class name is replaced completely with 'has-dropdown' so there is no differing class name or 'active'.

How can I fix this. Even to remove the JQuery in this case.

Answer (score 1):

Can you add the complete output code for the navigation menu. The code you pasted seems to be a stripped version. Moreover, WordPress adds 'current_page_item' class to the list item if it is currently being viewed.

For more info, check this [WordPress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu#Backward_Compatibility_with_wp_page_menu.28.29) on classes added to Navigation menu items.

Comment: Thank-you, it seems this is foundation.js functionality which the site has been built with

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mstoic for pointing out that this is not default WP functionality. This ended up being an unhelpful feature (for me) used in a WordPress stack.

I found the offending line and commented it out.

```
  $output .= "\n<ul class=\"dropdown\">\n";
  }

  function start_el(&$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0) {
    $item_html = '';
    parent::start_el($item_html, $item, $depth, $args);

    if ($item->is_dropdown && ($depth === 0)) {
      //$item_html = str_replace('<li', '<li class="has-dropdown not-click"', $item_html);
    ...
```